# how to create ruby on rails DB without error in AWS lightsail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to create database in ruby on rails.

This worked fine in the development environment.

but upload AWS lightsail, this occurred error.

What's the problem?

below using gem

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'kaminari'
gem 'faker'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog-aws'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'devise'
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem "bootstrap_form", ">= 4.0.0.alpha1"
gem 'rails', '5.0.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'figaro'
gem 'sunspot_solr'
gem 'sqlite3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'

end
```

below create controller

```
def create
    @person = Person.new(params.require(:person).permit(:name, :phone, :relation, :user_id, :image))

    if @person.save
        redirect_to people_path
    else
        redirect_to new_person_path
    end
end
```

below new.html.erb

```
<body class="main4">
<div class="container" style = "letter-spacing:-1px;">
    <center><h2 class="mt-5">연락처 추가</h2></center>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; display:flex; justify-content:center; margin-top: 10px; letter-spacing:-1px;">
    <%= form_for :person, :html => { :multipart => true, name: "personForm", :onsubmit => "return validateform();"}, url: people_path do |f| %>
        <div class="group">
            <%= f.file_field :image %>
            <span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
        </div>

        <br/>

        <div class="group">
            <%= f.text_field :name , required: true %>
            <span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
            <label>이름</label>
        </div>

        <br/>

        <div class="group">
            <%= f.number_field :phone , required: true %>
            <span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
            <label>전화번호</label>
        </div>

        <br/>

        <div class="group">
            <span>관계&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>
            <%= f.select(:relation, ['가족', '친구', '지인', '직장동료', '거래처', '기타'], {:class => 'form-control'})%>
        </div>

        <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>


        <p style="text-align:right;"><%= f.button :추가, label: '추가', :class => 'btn btn-outline-light' %></p>
    <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script>
    function validateform(){
          var personName = document.personForm.person_name;
          var personPhone = document.personForm.person_phone;
          var personImage = document.personForm.person_image;

          if(personName.value==""){
              alert("이름이 입력되지 않았습니다.");
              document.personForm.person_name.focus();
              document.getElementById('person_name').select();
              return false;
          }
          else if(personName.value.length > 4){
              alert("이름은 4글자 이하로 작성해주세요.");
              document.personForm.person_name.focus();
              document.getElementById('person_name').select();
              return false;
          }
          else if(personPhone.value==""){
              alert("전화번호가 입력되지 않았습니다.");
              document.personForm.person_phone.focus();
              document.getElementById('person_phone').select();
              return false;
          }
      }
</script>

</body>
```

below error scene in lightsail
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxKfB.png)

Again, it works in the development environment, but if you put it on the AWS lightsail, i'm get this error

Comment: Check the logs and post the error.

Comment: how can i check log in AWS lightsail?

Comment: SSH into the machine using the private key provided in the LightSail web dashboard.

Comment: this issue clear. thanks for your answer